# How do we pass properties to the tomcat context without using catalina.properties or is there a better way to inject the properties?

Tags: java, spring, docker, tomcat, secret-key

We are trying to move our projects to docker using the tomcat image and are a bit confused on how to inject the properties.

Our configuration right for a database config now looks like this:

/opt/tomcat/conf/context.xml

```
<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <ResourceLink name="DBCON"
                  global="jdbc/DBCON"
                  auth="Container"
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <Resource name="jdbc/DBCON"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="${oracle.database.url}"
              username="${oracle.database.username}"
              password="${oracle.database.password}"
              maxActive="100"
              maxIdle="20"
              minIdle="5"
              maxWait="10000"/>

</Context>
```

/opt/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties

```
some other properties ...
...
...
oracle.database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev-database.com:1521:dev1
oracle.database.username=user
oracle.database.password=pass
```

We are hoping to use secrets that get mapped to some location on the server `/some/loc/secrets/oracle.database.properties`, but don't undrstand how to inject those into the context.xml and we don't want to append or edit the cataline.properties file. We plan to move to spring-boot in the future, but the work is pretty drastic for a few projects.

I've found examples of `<Envrionment>` and `<PreResources>`, but don't see how we can tell the context.xml to actually use those properties.

Comment: What is the benefit of parametrizing such properties? I would place them statically in the tomcat.

Comment: @NiVeR the benefit is the security.

Comment: Why not use built-in [Docker's secret](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) feature with properties file? If you're using Spring, you can use `@PropertySource` annotation to load the file.

Comment: @NiVeR They need to be dynamic for the various environments and security.

@PraveenP We are using the docker secrets for other non-java/tomcat services. Won't using `@PropertySource` require code changes?

Comment: @flip66 Ok, but you will have different tomcats for each environment, no? It is a mattter of choice. You can also have a number of files `application-{profile}.properties` and fill the properties by profile.

Comment: @flip66 I know this is an old question, but what did you end up doing to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same problem with Dockerizing legacy Spring apps and would also like to be able to parameterize the context.xml using a secrets file. Ended up modifying catalina.properties, but doesn't seem elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set as system variables your DB properties:

`export JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Doracle.database.username=user -Doracle.database.password=pass`

Comment: We are doing that on our local, but we can't do that in PROD.

Comment: @flip66 May I ask why not? This is one of the prefered approaches by most developers.

Comment: @flip66 indeed why? This is very common approach. If you can not do this, then you should not use the JNDI. You should create your DB connections using Spring or why not, manually  and then, you can place your DB configuration in a properties file. Another approach is to not use the global `context.xml` file from `tomcat/conf` You have the option to include in your WEB-INF folder, if I'm not wrong, a custom context.xml file.

Comment: We have a strict requirement of not putting passwords in the environment variables which is why we are using docker secrets (files). We have considered mapping an entire context file for that app under `/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/someapp.xml`, but it seems like that defeats the purpose of building an image since we are trying to minimize OPs overhead.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned already the variables in the `context.xml` file must be available as system properties. From the Tomcat Configuration Reference:

> Tomcat configuration files are formatted as schemaless XML; elements
>   and attributes are case-sensitive. Apache Ant-style variable
>   substitution is supported; a system property with the name propname
>   may be used in a configuration file using the syntax ${propname}. All
>   system properties are available including those set using the -D
>   syntax, those automatically made available by the JVM and those
>   configured in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file

If you want those secret values in a different file you could override the CMD of the Tomcat docker container. That could be, for example, a shell script that reads the variables from the file, exports them as in @Octavian's answer and only then it starts the server.